# Convert Phonegap component to native code

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a page written in phonegap and I would like to take the header of the html page to a plugin written in native code.. can I do this? The header includes an image and an h1 tag.

Comment: Are you asking if you could render the top part of the app display using a plugin instead of mark-up or are you saying you will provide the content for that through a plugin? The former is probably not possible, the latter is.

Comment: @brahmana I need to render something like the top part of the app in the plugin, I was able to render the buttons but there is a text I need to render it and I wasn't able to. Is there any way that I can do this?